# iPhone site animations

Tags: iphone, ios, html, mobile, responsive-design

I have never made any site responsive for iPhone.

I was curious at how I would go about making a cross compatible site (iPhone, chrome,etc) where I have graphical animations(similar to flash). What tools are you supposed to use for graphic animations when you cannot use flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a complete cross compatible site the way to go about this is to build a webapp with HTML, HTML5, javascript, CSS. Nothing else would work across all devices. Forget Flash.

What you would need to do is have the server API's common for all devices but the way you present the data is customized to that device's form factor. This particular UI design technique is called - [Responsive Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

Basically the backend APIs remain, the data served from your backend could also be the same but the HTML templates served from backend could change depending on what device is making the request, this could be figured out from the client's user-agent eg. for iphone it is `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3`. For different clients you would have different user-agents. Plus you could have a small javascript which would send that particular device's screen dimensions back to the server. Again, this helps you to choose the correct templates to serve. Reg. HTML templates, you could have different sets of templates. like `web`, `ios`, `android` etc.. Also sometimes its difficult to have too many sets of templates (eg. we cant have a template set for every available android model out there). So we need some dynamic behavior i.e. specific javascript UI functions on the client to honor that devices screen dimensions etc.

This is too big and too general a topic to fully explain here. I have provided the wiki link and the technologies and terminology involved. Hope this helps your cause...

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a general question because I wanted general advice on a broad topic.